# How can i use XLNet to generate word embeddings

Tags: word-embedding

I want to know how i can use XLNet to generate word embeddings

I am currently using a word embedding model, but I want to compare its performance with XLNet

Comment: Thank you. So I am not the only one struggling with XLNet I don't know its not as simple as the other embedding to use like Elmo/Bert and Flair